# Validación textbox angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-directivas

Tengo un textbox con un boton que permite agregar x textbox en el formulario, este solo permite caracteres alfanumericos con una logitud de 16, la validacion funciona perfecto, el problema que estoy teniendo es que a todos los textbox me les coloca el mensaje de la validación del último textbox agregado, como se ve en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mensaje de "Este campo es requerido" solo debería aparecer para el último textbox ya que esta vacio.

En esta otra situación, en el último textbox coloque un carácter especial y el mensaje "La mac no es válida me la replica en todos":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```html
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class = "panel panel-default">
   <div class = "panel-heading">
    <b><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Formulario Contingencias aprovisionamiento</b>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="pedidoexiste">
     <span class="label label-warning">{{mensaje}}</span>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-show="pedidoguardado">
     <span class="label label-success">{{mensaje}}</span>
    </ul> 
   </div>
   <div class = "panel-body">
    <form  action=" " method="post" name="contact_form1" id="contact_form1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <ul class="list-group" >
          
          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : contact_form1.macEntra.$touched && contact_form1.macEntra.$invalid 'has-success': !contact_form1.macEntra.$touched && contact_form1.macEntra.$valid}">
           <li class="list-group-item small"><b>MAC entra: </b><br>
                              
                                                <button ng-click="addEquipoEntra()">Nuevo Equipo</button>
                                                <div ng-repeat="item in equiposEntran">

                                                 <input id="macEntra" name="macEntra" type="text" ng-model="form.value" required ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}$/" placeholder="Mac entra">

                                                 
  

  <p class="help-block" ng-show="contact_form1.macEntra.$error.required">Este campo es requerido</p>
  <p style="color:red;"class="help-block" ng-show="contact_form1.macEntra.$error.pattern">La MAC no es válida</p>

                                                </div>
                             </li>
                            </div>



         </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
     </form> 
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

El boto de agregar mac no funciona acá por que eso lo tengo en un js. Quien me pueda orientar le agradezco de antemano.

Comment: He publicado una respuesta, espero que te sirva, si no es así, es necesario que coloques el contenido **html** completo donde tienes el **form**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es por que estas haciendo un `ng-repeat` de `equiposEntran` y entonces te crea varios `items` en este caso `inputs`

```
<input id="macEntra" name="macEntra" type="text"
 ng-model="form.value" required ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}$/" placeholder="Mac entra"><br>
```

Entonces donde tienes `ng-show="contact_form1.macEntra.$error.pattern"` que es para que aparezca el error... Estas llamando al mismo **name** `macEntra` del `form` y por ende te los crea en todos los `input`, te recomiendo que analices bien lo que necesitas y si es necesario crear `inputs` diferentes para que no te suceda lo mismo, quedo atento si necesitas ayuda.

***ACTUALIZACIÓN***
He realizado lo siguiente, debes hacer que los `input` sean dinámicos para poder aplicar esta validación, lo he hecho con el `$index` del `ng-repeat`... Entonces cambias el `name` del `input` por esté: `name="macEntra{{ $index }}"` y asi mismo donde se llame este `name` le agregamos el `{{ $index }}`.
 
 He cambiado la validación que tienes por está:

```
<p style="color:red;"class="help-block" ng-show="contact_form1.macEntra{{ $index }}.$touched && contact_form1.macEntra{{ $index }}.$invalid">La MAC no es válida</p>
```

Espero que funcione, quedo atento.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
    app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

        $scope.equiposEntran = [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Carlos"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Agustin"
            }
        ];
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-aria.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-messages.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/master/angular-material.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class = "panel panel-default">
     <div class = "panel-body">
      <form  action=" " method="post" name="contact_form1" id="contact_form1">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <ul class="list-group" >

          <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : contact_form1.macEntra.$touched && contact_form1.macEntra.$invalid 'has-success': !contact_form1.macEntra.$touched && contact_form1.macEntra.$valid}">
           <li class="list-group-item small"><b>MAC entra: </b><br>
            <button ng-click="addEquipoEntra()">Nuevo Equipo</button>
            <div ng-repeat="item in equiposEntran track by $index">
             <!--<input ng-model="item.value" placeholder="Mac entra" name="macEntra" capitalize required>-->
             <input id="macEntra" name="macEntra{{ $index }}" type="text" ng-model="form.value" required ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,16}$/" placeholder="Mac entra">

             <!--<input id="nif" name="nif" type="text" ng-model="seguro.nif" required ng-pattern="/(^[X-Z]\d{7}[A-Z]$)|(^\d{8}[A-Z]$)/" />-->

             <p class="help-block" ng-show="contact_form1.macEntra{{ $index }}.$error.required">Este campo es requerido</p>
             <p style="color:red;"class="help-block" ng-show="contact_form1.macEntra{{ $index }}.$touched && contact_form1.macEntra{{ $index }}.$invalid">La MAC no es válida</p>

            </div>
           </li>
          </div>
         </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
      </form> 
     </div>
    </div>  
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Asi es como dice TheVicious

Comment: @TheVicious gracias por tu respuesta, pero como creo los inputs ? teniendo en cuenta que se agrega una cantidad indeterminada de textbox?

Comment: @HectorEcheverri Puedes agregar el contenido **HTML** completo que conforma el **ng-repeat** para poder ayudarte con la estructura y el contenido del form **contact_form1** también.

Comment: @TheVicious  acabo de colocar el html completo.

Comment: @HectorEcheverri ok listo, voy a ver tu problema y estaré editando mi respuesta para una nueva actualización.

Comment: @TheVicious Perfecto, tal cual eso era lo que requería. Muchas gracias hermano por tu tiempo.